# CMD : Merge Files Echo date and file name to merged file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt, text-formatting

I have used the below code to merge .cpp files in a directory.This code was a result of question asked in super user but there are no replies since my question was edited.So please don't mark this question as duplicate .

```
  @echo off
  cd C:\test
   echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<style^> pre {page-break-after: always;}  ^</style^>^</head^>^<body^> >merged.html
  for /r %%f in (*.cpp) do (
   echo ^<pre^>
   echo File Name   : //Here i want the file name of each program without .cpp extension 
   echo Description :
   echo Author      : Name
   echo Date        : //Here i want the date associated with each file DD-MM-YYYY
   echo.
   type "%%f"
   echo ^</pre^>
  ) >> merged.html
  echo ^</body^>^</html^> >> merged.html
```

**Current Merged.html file**

```
File name  : 
Desciption :
Author     : Name
Date       :
 #include 
int main()
{ 
.....

.....

.....
}
Then the second file on the next page .
```

**Issue with the above code**

It is omitting the header file names i.e

In the orignal file i have #include but in the merged file 
i'm only having #include.I guess the problem is due to the "<" and ">" .

**What i need**

I need the date associated with each program file in the merged file after Date : (See my code above, Read the commented part) .Also i need the file name of each program after File name : like abc(without the extension .cpp in the file).

Comment: So you just need to know how to get the date when the file was last modified and the extensionless file name? How does this have anything to do with merging then?

Comment: @SomethingDark Suppose if there are 2 files 1.pgm_1.cpp date : 5-5-2015 and 2.pgm_2.cpp date : 2-3-2015 . Now while merging i'm adding 4 lines on top of each program .Consider the case of file 1: File name : (here i need pgm.cpp without extension .cpp) then Description :(I will fill after converting it to pdf) then Author : myName and then finally Date : (here i need to have the date 5-5-2015 ) like for the second file also .

Comment: Yes, but this is still essentially a case of processing multiple files, since you don't have a problem with the actual merging process.

Comment: I have got a plenty of .cpp files and it would be very difficult adding the date and file name on each page. That why i  asked this question.

Comment: @SomethingDark help me find a solution

Comment: @manutd Please don't keep changing your question on [su] to add new requirements after you have already have an answer. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://superuser/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry for the same mistake being repeated twice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<style^> pre {page-break-after: always;}  ^</style^>^</head^>^<body^> >u:\newfile.txt
for /r %%f in (*.cpp) do (
 echo ^<pre^>
 echo File Name   : %%~nf 
 echo Description :
 echo Author      : Name
 FOR /f %%d IN ("%%~tf") DO echo Date        : %%d
 echo.
 type "%%f"
 echo ^</pre^>
)>>u:\newfile.txt
echo ^</body^>^</html^> >> u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Produces u:\newfile.txt. I removed your `cd` to your source directory to suit my testing.

The filename is relatively simple, just `%%~nf` - see the documentation on `for` from the prompt

```
for /?
```

You don't tell us what format you use for your date, so manipulating that is a topic in itself (that has been covered many times over on SO). The format I use is `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss` so I can use the default `tokens=1delims=`. If as seems likely, you are using `DDDday dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss` then you'd need to use `FOR /f "tokens=2" %%d IN...`

I could find no problem with redirectors in the `.cpp` files (but please don't assume that people have samples of or familiarity with them.)

Now - it's going to be a real pain maintaining this as you'd need to re-edit the file over and over again to insert the names and descriptions.

Try this:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<style^> pre {page-break-after: always;}  ^</style^>^</head^>^<body^> >u:\newfile.txt
for /r %%f in (*.cpp) do (
 echo ^<pre^>
 echo File Name   : %%~nf
 SET "namefound="
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3delims=|" %%p IN (q29056600.txt) DO IF /i "%%p"=="%%~nxf" (
  echo Description : %%q
  echo Author      : %%r
  SET namefound=Y
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED namefound (
  echo Description :
  echo Author      : Name
 )
 FOR /f %%d IN ("%%~tf") DO echo Date        : %%d
 echo.
 type "%%f"
 echo ^</pre^>
)>>u:\newfile.txt
echo ^</body^>^</html^> >> u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Where the file `q29056600.txt` contains

```
hello.cpp|Hello World version 1|Fred Nurk
helloworld.cpp|Hello World version Two|Joe Bloggs
```

That is, filename description autor separated by pipes. The extra code

- clears a flag `namefound`
- reads your descriptions file. If it finds a match, outputs the description and author and sets the flag
- if the flag is not set (filename not found in file) then produce your dummy lines

---

Here's the above with a constant `author` line. You'd simply need to omit the author column from the support file.

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<style^> pre {page-break-after: always;}  ^</style^>^</head^>^<body^> >u:\newfile.txt
for /r %%f in (*.cpp) do (
 echo ^<pre^>
 echo File Name   : %%~nf
 SET "namefound="
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=|" %%p IN (q29056600.txt) DO IF /i "%%p"=="%%~nxf" (
  echo Description : %%q
  SET namefound=Y
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED namefound (
  echo Description :
 )
 echo Author      : Name
 FOR /f %%d IN ("%%~tf") DO echo Date        : %%d
 echo.
 type "%%f"
 echo ^</pre^>
)>>u:\newfile.txt
echo ^</body^>^</html^> >> u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

As for the problem with missing text: I suspect you aren't looking at the file with a text editor like `notepad` but with some variety of HTML viewer, so the missing data is being interpreted as HTML.

---

If I am correct about the `<>` problem, then the following may be a fix:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL

echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<style^> pre {page-break-after: always;}  ^</style^>^</head^>^<body^> >u:\newfile.txt
for /r %%f in (*.cpp) do (
 echo ^<pre^>
 echo File Name   : %%~nf
 SET "namefound="
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=|" %%p IN (q29056600.txt) DO IF /i "%%p"=="%%~nxf" (
  echo Description : %%q
  SET namefound=Y
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED namefound (
  echo Description :
 )
 echo Author      : Name
 FOR /f %%d IN ("%%~tf") DO echo Date        : %%d
 echo.
 TYPE "%%f"|sed "s/\x3c/\&lt\x3b/g;s/\x3e/\&gt\x3b/g;s/\x25/\&#37\x3b/g"
 echo ^</pre^>
)>>u:\newfile.txt
echo ^</body^>^</html^> >> u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that this includes `sed` - a free utility. I used GNUSED.

Comment: But in the merged file there is only #include no header file (<iostream.h>) after that .

Comment: I could not reproduce your symptoms. The `<iostream.h>` appeared perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful idea In the second code,i only want to have the file description for each file .So what should i do for that .The author name is same for all.

Comment: But i have problem .  I Just copied the entire code and it's giving the same result without the headerfile .I think the problem lies with the .html file i'm using .html file since i need to have each program in a new page.

Comment: Another problem after certain pages some programs are only upto a for(i=0 ; and the next program begins right from there . Then after some programs giving the same result there is not issue with other programs.

Comment: @manutd html files do not have any concept of new page. New pages are a concept for printers and word processors.